# How include dependencies in jar during sbt test:package goal?

Tags: scala, jar, dependencies, sbt, artifact

Official documentation [said](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Artifacts.html) that artifact can be easy published after `test:package` task. But how include dependencies to it during this task?

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to have all of your dependencies included in one "fat" jar you can use sbt-assembly plugin which inspired by Maven's assembly plugin that does the same. You can find documentation and examples here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly